# Sass BEM modifiers and children

Tags: sass, parent-child, bem

I have the following BEM setup:

```
  .mytable {
      font-size: 16px;
        margin: 30px 0;
      &--standard {
        border: 1px solid red;
        &__row {
          border: 1px solid blue;
        }
      }
```

What I am trying to do is apply the row styles only to the modified table class.

This outputs the following

```
.mytable--standard__row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Which is obviously not what I am trying to achieve.

Is there a neat/standard way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you please write the expected  outputs to understand your needs

Comment: What’s the target? Do you wan to apply styles to the rows on table? You request is not clear.

Comment: "which is obviously incorrect" no, that selector and its rules are correctly generated from the sass you've provided. Additionally that's an appropriate way to handle modifiers in BEM*. What actual selector do you think you should be generating? (* there are multiple variants of BEM so there may be some where that selector is not desirable, you'll need to be specific about which variant you're using).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add another ampersand after the modifier to get the desired output:

```
.mytable {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 30px 0;

  &--standard {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  &--standard & { //<-- 

    &__row{
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }

    &__some-other-element{}

  }

}
```

Comment: Great answer and not that well known or documented as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

We use:

```
  .mytable {
      font-size: 16px;
        margin: 30px 0;
      &--standard {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      &--standard &__row {
          border: 1px solid blue;
      }
  }
```

Its not ideal (a `&&` grandparent selector would be nice), but its the best we could come up with so far